# How to make ansible wait for a port to be ready?

Tags: ansible

I intended to wait for a port to be ready so used "wait_for"

```
- name: Wait for service to be ready
  wait_for:
    host: 192.168.1.70
    port: 8080
```

However it only waits for 300 seconds and then fails.

```
TASK [Wait for service to be ready] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 300, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for 192.168.1.70:8080"}
```

So, I added an "until" :

```
- name: Wait for service to be ready
  wait_for:
    host: 192.168.1.70
    port: 8080
  register: port8080
  until: port8080.failed == "false"
```

Instead, I get an error :

```
TASK [Wait for ssh to be ready] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'port8080.failed == \"false\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (port8080.failed == \"false\"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'failed'"}
```

BUT if I remove the "until" and add a debug statement, I can see that **port8080.failed** is set to either true or false as expected.

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
  "port8080": {
     "changed": false, 
     "elapsed": 0, 
     "failed": false,
```

First question : Is this an ansible bug or am I doing something wrong?
Second question : How can I make my script wait for a connection (for longer than 300 seconds)?

(NB I am actually waiting for a database to start, 300 seconds is too short a time for the DB to start. BUT I don't want to wait for 300 seconds, in case I'm re-running the script and the DB is already running.)

Comment: If you suspect it's a bug, please tell us what version you're using. Although I think you should simply try with nbari's answer. To use delay, sleep and timeout variables.

Comment: Why would using `until` without `retries` be a bug? Read: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops

Comment: Retries defaults to 1. And if I set it to 2. I still get " 'dict object' has no attribute 'failed' " and it crashed out without waiting at all. When the "port22" dict object does have an attribute failed, because I can debug: msg="{{port22.failed}}" if I take the "until" out.

Comment: ansible --version
ansible 2.4.2.0

Comment: And : ansible --version
ansible 2.4.3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give a try to [wait_for_connection](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/wait_for_connection_module.html) for example this will work when you reboot your system and want to wait until is reachable/usable:

```
- name: Something that may reboot
  shell: echo "true"
  register: should_reboot

- name: Rebooting ...
  shell: sleep 2 && /sbin/shutdown -r now "Reboot required"
  async: 1
  poll: 0
  ignore_errors: true
  register: rebooting
  when: should_reboot.stdout == "true"

- name: Wait for rebooted servers to come back
  wait_for_connection:
    connect_timeout: 20
    sleep: 5
    delay: 5
    timeout: 60
  when: rebooting|changed
```

For checking/testing if a remote host is up this may work:

```
- name: Wait for service to be ready
  wait_for:
    port: 8080
    host: 127.0.0.1
    connect_timeout: 3
    delay: 3
    timeout: 30
```

For testing I created a local port 8080 using [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat), for example:

```
nc -l 8080
```

if the port is not open you will get something like:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 30, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for localhost:8080"}
```

When the port is open you run the playybook will notice that one connected it will also exit, in case you want to keep it permanent use something like:

```
nc -kl 8080
```

Comment: Hi @techraf, thanks for the heads up, it would be only false if the previous task would not change but for this to happen would require also a `when: should_reboot` for example.

Comment: And when the `when: rebooting` condition would be false (after the edit)?

Comment: In the case of having only this two tasks it will never be false

Comment: Let’s say that you create another task the one sets to false `should_reboot` and like mentioned before in the rebooting task you have a `when: should_reboot` so there will be no rebooting and both task will be skipped, in any case given a try at the end we could improve the answer with a better example

Comment: Did you already tried? Would be nice to se some code with all this use cases at least to see how and when is either true/false

Comment: The idea of trying is just to “test”, maybe I am totally wrong and you could enlighten me with your findings and even better contribute with a better answer

Comment: Please create another question for this specific topic

Comment: Hi @techraf I already answered your questions but since I probably confused you that’s why I suggested to try, in any case please find more info about ansible conditionals here http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html

Comment: Hi @techraf thanks for letting me know, if I may ask could you  please elaborate more in a way it could be easy to explain/understand, thanks in advance

Comment: I already elaborated: **please answer when this condition would evaluate to `false`** ― find one single instance and answer it in a comment. Start your answer with: **`rebooting` variable will have a value of `false` when ...** and fill up the rest.

Comment: That wasn’t very useful but thanks anyway, in any case I would suggest creating another question regarding your concerns since this is going a little off topic, there I will be more than happy to comment.

Comment: ["You should submit a comment if you want to: Request **clarification** from the author"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). I want a clarification from the author of this answer and I used comment specifically for this purpose.　・　If you claim something "*is going a little off topic*" please quote a specific rule or meta post.　・　The fact that the author refuses to give a clarification does not invalidate a request for clarification itself.

Comment: hi @techraf First I would please ask you to stop deleting/modifying your comments, it confuses more rather than helping, second if you want to clarify/ suggest something then please please go straight to the point with all respect your attitude is not helping much, indeed please read the bottom of the page you just send: Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote a better answer if appropriate);

Comment: You are wrong about the purpose and usage of comments on SO. They are not for extended discussion. **Please delete** your comments which are not relevant anymore.　・　I repeat if you missed my clarification request: "Start your answer with: **`rebooting` variable will have a value of false when ...** and fill up the rest."　・　That simple.

Comment: This only works when the instance is defined as an ansible host. In my case, it isn't. "(I actually want to wait for a database to be ready, but it was easier to rewrite the example with port 22)"

Comment: hi @MaxAllan I updated the answer hoping it can give you a better idea for both cases

Comment: Your latest update is definitely a bug (probably in the docs rather than the application). The documentation for wait_for says :
"timeout :
Maximum number of seconds to wait for, when used with another condition it will force an error."

And yet it doesn't force an error!! It does however adjust the maximum wait_for timeout, which is what I want (obviously not setting it to 30 like you suggest but 99999) I just need to add that one line to my original command "timeout: 99999". And ignore the documentation...